# how to reinitialize an angularjs application

Tags: soap, soap-client, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.thisarray = globalObj;

    $scope.loadthis = function (index) {
        return thisarray[index];
    }
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<table ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="element in thisarray">
            {{loadthis($index)}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm loading some data through a `SOAP` callback:

```
    SOAPCLient.invoke(url, methodName, pl, true, function(obj) {globalObj = obj;

    **angular.bootstrap("html");**//here is where I try to reinitialize the app 

});
```

If you look at the `SOAP` call, I use `bootstrap` to reinitialize the app, but it has not been working. `loadthis` does not display any data inside the HTML table. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for changes to the SOAP using $.watch and then $.apply when trying to force a push. See examples of how to use [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/)

Answer (score 1):

You should not be re-initializing AngularJS application every time you've got data arriving from an external source. Instead of destroying and re-creating AngularJS the way to go would be to use $apply method on a scope object.

The pseudo-code (in your controller) would be like:

```
SOAPCLient.invoke(url, methodName, pl, true, function(obj) {
    $scope.apply(function(){
        $scope.thisarray = obj;
    });
});
```

Also, if I understand your code correctly you would invoke a SOAP call for each item in a repeater (ng-repeat) while your SOAP call is bringing back data for all objects. So the better approach would be to do a SOAP call (as in a snippet above), assign data to a variable in a scope and let the ngRepeat do its magic.

I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve here so having a jsFiddle / plunker with your code would help to provide more detailed response.