# AngularJS not responding when pages is pulled in with ajax using jquery mobile, how to get angular to work with subsequent jqm pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

Using jquery mobile and angularjs I am using the Single page template. In the first page angular is working as expected but in subsequent pages it is as if angular is not registered.

When I change to using the Multi-page strategy its working.

I have tried to get angular to work on pageinit:

```
$(document).delegate("#Page2", "pageinit", function () {
    angular.bootstrap($("#Page2"), ['APP']);
});
```

I also tried the suggestions [how to reinitialize an angularjs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022831/how-to-reinitialize-an-angularjs-application)  with no luck.

I am using jqm 1.3.0-rc.1 and the jquery-mobile-angular-adapter is not playing nicely with it. 
Is there any way that I can get angular to work on subsequent pages.

Comment: I would avoid trying to re-initialize an AngularJS application. As far as AngularJS would be concerned, it's not even a single-page application anymore - your services, etc., would not share state between page changes. So what's the advantage of using the single-page strategy?

Comment: I'm using jquery mobile the single page template: [link](www.jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-template.html)

Comment: Not looking to re initialize angular just trying to get it to work after content has been added to the dom when jqm hav pulled it in using ajax.

Comment: Oh! If you're loading HTML from a template outside of AngularJS, you'll need to `$compile` it before adding it to the DOM. Throw up a really simple Plunker or Fiddle and I'll see if I can show you what I mean.